# Not all fields are visible for posts with a status_type of mobile_status_update

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to access posts from the NSK Americas page. In some cases, such as with this post: https://www.facebook.com/167492273414157/posts/1631019517061418/, the messages seem to be missing.

I'm using either Graph API v7.0 or v8.0 to retrieve these posts using this link: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Fposts%3Ffields%3Did%2C%20message%2Cpicture%2Cpermalink_url%2Cupdated_time%2Clikes.summary(true)%2Cstatus_type%26debug%3Dall%26limit%3D10&version=v7.0.

For the mentioned post (and several others), the response does not include the message field.

```
    {
  "id": "167492273414157_1629006857262684",
  "picture": "https://scontent-lht6-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/s130x130/109800992_10158717648158829_4051834528451244978_o.jpg?_nc_cat=103&_nc_sid=9e2e56&_nc_ohc=j3z1Nm2SH_UAX8hDKTY&_nc_ht=scontent-lht6-1.xx&_nc_tp=7&oh=8b624b596f483178da23b3a48790a7d3&oe=5F4FC8A2",
  "permalink_url": "https://www.facebook.com/167492273414157/posts/1629006857262684/",
  "updated_time": "2020-07-19T04:30:04+0000",
  "likes": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "169605148828",
        "name": "UC Berkeley FSAE"
      }
    ],
    "paging": {
      "cursors": {
        "before": "QVFIUmszbm1QOTJXRlFWR21FcFEtVFZAnSHJFdk9MR1hTZAWdZAdXZAZAcVlxMGtlMFQzeHNZAWDY5UHF6RWh1VXVIYmJCLW0wVl8ySUp3a203VEdfbXlwV0Y4dy1R",
        "after": "QVFIUjl3WEgzT3lNWThyeVJzREZANdGFmOEdvVTFwMUdoWl9FOG5jaHpYeFZAnX21wcnZACOGtNdk9USktHNm95SDhJVVBnb0gxek9TZAWFNZAHd3UUg0d3pCQnJB"
      }
    },
    "summary": {
      "total_count": 3,
      "can_like": true,
      "has_liked": false
    }
  },
  "status_type": "mobile_status_update"
}
```

Even directly calling the post fails to fetch the message: graph.facebook.com/167492273414157_1629006857262684?fields=id,message,story,status_type.

The response does not contain a message:

```
{
  "id": "167492273414157_1629006857262684",
  "status_type": "mobile_status_update"
}
```

I'm struggling to identify what might be causing this issue. The common factor appears to be that all posts lacking the message field have a status_type of mobile_status_update.

I'm seeking assistance as this is causing frustration for one of our customers.

Thank you,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

Try the `attachments` field. Apparently Facebook sticks most of the relevant data into that one, for the `mobile_status_update` post type.